# Git for Windows does not read SSH config

Tags: git, ssh

I have what I believe to be a perfectly valid SSH config file, but git is always defaulting to my `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key and nothing else.

Here's an example of my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host account1
    Hostname github.com
    User user1
    IdentityFile C:\Users\Me\.ssh\github\id_rsa_account1

Host account2
    Hostname github.com
    User user2
    IdentityFile C:\Users\Me\.ssh\github\id_rsa_account2
```

I'm trying to clone a repo like this: `git clone git@github.com:account2/my-repo.git`

No matter what I try, it keeps using the `id_rsa` file. If I remove the `id_rsa`, it uses nothing and just immediately fails.

Edit:

- SSH config is in the correct location: `~/.ssh/config`
- SSH config has the correct permissions
- Git config has nothing overriding SSH settings
- Git is updated to the latest version
- Manually setting the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` variable does nothing, whether it's Git's bundled `ssh.exe` or my locally installed one. Even specifying the `-F ~\.ssh\config` option does nothing. It does error if I give it an invalid command though, so it is definitely using this setting.

Comment: The hostname you should give in the URL when you clone is `account2` - not `github.com` and `account1` instead of `bitbucket.org`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things to fix here:

1. Add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to each stanza. This will cause the ssh-agent to try only the specified identity, instead of trying all known identities.
2. Remove the `User user2` from the GitHub stanza. It doesn't matter what your real username is; when it comes to SSH, GitHub only uses the username `git`. (It's been a while since I last used Bitbucket, but back in 2019-ish they allowed Git operations over SSH with your real username.)
3. If you want the SSH client to use specific parameters defined in the SSH config, then either change the config to replace `Host account2` with `Host github.com`, or change your clone command to `git clone account2:owner/repo`. Similarly, to use the Bitbucket-specific things, either change `Host account1` to `Host bitbucket.org` or use `git clone account1:owner/repo`.

As an aside: why are you using separate SSH keys for discrete services?

Comment: Thank you! I did all this, plus only other thing was I actually have to set the User to `git` in the config file myself or it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Location of the SSH config file: Make sure your SSH config file is located in the correct directory. By default, the SSH config file should be located at ~/.ssh/config (i.e., C:\Users\username.ssh\config on Windows). You can check the location of your SSH config file by running the command ssh -v.

Permissions of the SSH config file: Make sure the permissions on your SSH config file are set correctly. The file should only be readable by you (chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config on Linux/MacOS, or by going to the file properties in Windows and removing all groups and users except for yourself).

Check Git's config file: Make sure that Git is not overriding your SSH config by checking Git's config file. Run the command git config --global -e to open Git's config file and look for any entries related to SSH.

Check Git's version: Make sure you have the latest version of Git for Windows installed, as older versions may not support all features.

If none of these solutions work, you can try setting the GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment variable to explicitly specify the path to your SSH executable and/or adding the -F option to specify the path to your SSH config file. For example, you can run GIT_SSH_COMMAND="C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe" git clone git@github.com:username/repo.git to explicitly specify the path to your SSH executable.

Comment: Nothing... I legitimately did try everything you suggested. The file is in `~\.ssh\config`, right next to my `id_rsa` that currently does work.

Answer (score 0):

@chrispytoes
The only thing you maybe forgot is adding your new hosts' private keys to your ssh-agent. You could do this via:

```
ssh-add "C:\Users\Me\.ssh\github\id_rsa_account1"
ssh-add "C:\Users\Me\.ssh\github\id_rsa_account2"
```

And then, It would be better to restart your ssh-agent service in PowerShell (as administrator):

```
 Restart-Service ssh-agent
```

In addition, [here](https://gist.github.com/Sotatek-NuiTran/a20d6827d874ca5f5b7b01e1a6d8fd01) you can find a step-by-step setup.
I hope it will work.